# passing user defined argument to setParseAction in pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have something like following (simplified version)

```
class ParseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, tokens):
         # do some processing on tokens

expr = Word().setParseAction(ParseClass)
```

Is there any way to send some user-defined argument to **init** function of ParseClass? Like some context etc. So that I will have -

```
class ParseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, tokens, context):
         # do some processing on tokens based on context

expr = Word().setParseAction(ParseClass, context)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

I would expect that if the former works, then the latter could be accomplished via:

```
expr = Word().setParseAction(lambda tokens: ParseClass(tokens,context) )
```

but I don't know pyparsing.  (I'll happily delete this if it doesn't work)

Comment: @PaulMcGuire -- Good to know I wasn't in left field.

Answer (score 4):

Use a function that takes your context, and returns the appropriate parse action as its return value:

```
def replaceWith(replacementString):
    def parseAction(string, loc, tokens):
        return replacementString
    return parseAction

expr = Word(alphas).setParseAction(replaceWith("xyzzy"))

print OneOrMore(expr).parseString("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
```

Prints:

```
['xyzzy', 'xyzzy', 'xyzzy', 'xyzzy', 'xyzzy', 'xyzzy', 'xyzzy', 'xyzzy', 'xyzzy']
```

Or use transformString:

```
>>> print expr.transformString("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
xyzzy xyzzy xyzzy xyzzy xyzzy xyzzy xyzzy xyzzy xyzzy.
```